# Front camera on Nexus 4: no HDR, and downgraded from 2MP to 1.2MP?

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, front-camera

In Nexus 4, why is the front camera downgraded to 1.2 MP only, as it was 2MP initially? And also, we had an option of HDR in that as well, which is absent in Lollipop 5.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

From [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_4_e960-5048.php), the secondary (front) camera has 1.3 MP, and the camera settings provide 1.2 MP as the highest, so I'm not sure if it was 2 MP before. (Camera resolution is related tightly to hardware capability, so it's strange to be able to have higher resolution in the first place).

As for missing HDR, it seems it's caused by Google Camera, as [reported by other on Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/3AaeEWzWnOE). Google Camera is the default camera app on Lollipop. Previously, Android uses AOSP (Android Open Source Project) Camera as the default camera app, and it supports HDR on front camera. The intended solution is to use AOSP camera back, as some people have ported and published them on Play Store, since it's open-source:

1. [Nexus Camera: KitKat Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radcam.camera) (free)
2. [Camera KK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.camerakk) (adware)

Comment: But how can camera settings be changed as it is the hardware property?? & are these camera options provided by you fully proven??

Comment: It's possible to use smaller resolution (MP) because camera app will capture raw image, and compress to designate resolution. As for HDR, it's a technology in photography, and it's not related to hardware. There is a different HDR technology used in stock and Google camera, so maybe that's the reason Google remove it's HDR for front camera. As for the options, I have tested it personally on my Nexus 4.